# What does the scala case class equality function do?

Tags: scala, case-class

According to [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch04s15.html), Scala case classes automatically generates an equality method. However:

```
class SomeCaseClass(val string:String) {}

val a = "123"
assertTrue( a.equals( a ) )  // Passes
assertTrue( new SomeCaseClass(a).equals( new SomeCaseClass(a) ) ) // Fails, Scala 2.10
```

So, what does this automatically generated equals method do?

Comment: You're missing the `case` before your `class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a case class. That's the case class:

```
scala> case class SomeCaseClass(string: String)
defined class SomeCaseClass

scala> val a = "123"
a: String = 123

scala> SomeCaseClass(a) == SomeCaseClass(a)
res1: Boolean = true
```

`==` is just a syntax sugar for `equals`

In your example, you've just called `equals` (you'll get same result with `===`) on regular object (this `equals` is not automatically generated), so it checked just referential equality.

P.S. You may notice that case class doesn't require `new` as it has automatically generated companion object. It doesn't require `val` in constructor as it assumes it by default. `{}` isn't mandatory for both regular and case classess.

Comment: @user48956 Lol! I'm feeling like Captain Obvious :)